# Order of index in Lorentz transform

Tags: special-relativity, soft-question, notation

I am reading Schwartz's "QFT and the standard model". On pg 13 he gives the Lorentz transform of a rotation around the x-axis:

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \cos  \theta _x & \sin  \theta _x \\
 0 & 0 & -\sin  \theta _x & \cos  \theta _x \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

For a boost along the x-axis he gives:

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \cosh  \beta _x & \sinh  \beta _x & 0 & 0 \\
 \sinh  \beta _x & \cosh  \beta _x & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

I believe this corresponds to the Lorentz transform in the form $\Lambda^\alpha{}_\beta$. I believe the first index is the row and the second is the column. But at the bottom of the pg he has
$
V^\mu=\Lambda_\nu^\mu V^\nu.
$
as though the order of the indices on $\Lambda$ doesn't matter. But surely they do matter as $\Lambda^\alpha{}_\beta\not=\Lambda_\beta{}^\alpha$ in general?

Comment: This question seems to be about a typographic detail in a specific book.

Comment: @bechira I think it would be interesting to know as its otherwise such a good qft textbook. I think the answer is by $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ he means $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

His notation is not ambiguous because the expression
$$V^{'\mu} \equiv \Lambda^\mu_\nu V^\nu$$
can only mean sum along the $\nu$ component. Since $\Lambda$ is a representation of the Lorentz group, it is a linear operator, hence it can only act on a vector by the usual way that matrices act on vectors. Hence the above is unambiguous.

**Longer answer**

I'll explain why in general this notation is unambiguous.

The convention is the following: the upper index denotes a vector index and the lower index denotes a dual vector index and. That is, for a general rank $(p, q)$ tensor, one would usually write

$$
 T^{\mu_1...\mu_p}_{\nu_1...\nu_q} \partial_{\mu_1} \otimes ... \otimes \partial_{\mu_p} \otimes dx^{\nu_1}... dx^{\nu_q}
$$

where $\{\partial_\mu\}$ denotes a basis for your vector space and ${dx^\nu}$ denotes a basis for its [dual vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space). (The notation I chose is from differential geometry, which is certainly useful when you define a field theory in over a general spacetime manifold).

As a special case, a linear transformation is a rank $(1,1)$ tensor. Namely $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ unambiguously denotes components of the tensor:

$$\Lambda^\mu_\nu ~\partial_\mu \otimes dx^\nu$$

Acting on a vector $V \equiv V^\tau \partial_\tau$, we get:

$$\Lambda[V] \\
= \Lambda^\mu_\nu ~\partial_\mu \otimes dx^\nu [V^\tau \partial_\tau] \\
= \Lambda^\mu_\nu V^\tau (\partial_\tau dx^\nu) ~\partial_\mu \\ 
= \Lambda^\mu_\nu V^\tau  \delta_\tau^\nu  ~\partial_\mu \\
= \Lambda^\mu_\nu V^\nu  ~\partial_\mu $$

Observe no horizontal padding in the indices are needed to make these manipulations unambiguous.

Comment: but $\Lambda^\mu_{\ \nu}$ is not a tensor, right?

Comment: @Chan Why not? It's a well-defined multi linear operator in any basis.